# How to setup logstash on Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, logstash

I have to setup ELK using salesforce but am struck at configuring logstash for Salesforce .Any info provided would be helpful to solve this issue.I could not find info in Google about this.

Answer (score 1):

If you look for just tutorials about integration of SF and logstash, possible these articles will be useful for you:

- [How to Analyze Salesforce Data with the ELK Stack](http://logz.io/blog/analyze-salesforce-elk-stack/)
- [Analyzing Salesforce Data with Logstash, Elasticsearch, and Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/blog/analyzing-salesforce-data-with-logstash-elasticsearch-kibana)

[Here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-salesforce) is plugin for Logstash for pulling objects from salesforce.

If you have have some specific issues, please describe it more widely.